# How to set a initial value in sequelize model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I need my id start not in 1. I tried to use initialAutoIncrement but not working.

My id should start in 1000, and increment by one.

```
id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },

    initialAutoIncrement: 1000,
    timestamps: false
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
async function myTest() {
    await sequelize.queryInterface.createTable('User', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
    }, {
        initialAutoIncrement: 1000
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Ill try it.